# Error exporting Xcode archive since version 13.2.1

Tags: xcode

We have been getting an error in exporting an archive since the release of Xcode 13.2.1, and are also seeing it in 13.3.  (13.1 works great)

The error is:

```
Reached end of file while looking for: Mach-O slice.
```

I get this when exporting on our jenkins/fastlane server as well on my development machine.

Curious if anyone has found a solution for this?

Comment: Did you try running `project > clean` to clear out any broken binaries/imports?

Comment: Can you post the build log, it's hard to debug based only on the failing line

Answer (score 0):

It can be an internal issue with malformed library files, try to reload it.

You can try: export_xcargs: "-allowProvisioningUpdates"